# How to parse a matrix in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I created a matrix of 0s using `join()`. Assignment works if I hotcode it. If I get as an input, it doesn't work.

```
theatre=[]
for i in range(5):
  theatre.append(["0"]*5)
def print_screen(theatre):
  for i in theatre:
    print(" ".join(i))
print_screen(theatre)

theatre[int(raw_input("Enter row"))][int(raw_input("Enter col"))]=="x" ## this doesn't work
theatre[0][1]="x" ## This is working.
```

Comment: When writing questions, please put the main part of your commentary in the question body, and do not try to stuff it into the title. You can leave out "please help me anyone" and other forms of begging, readers know you need help! I have tried to write a succinct title, but you may wish to edit that further.

Comment: Have you looked at the values and types that `int(raw_input(...))` is creating in each case? I would recommend moving those to separate variables, as the code is getting rather difficult to read, since it is all squashed onto one line.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Boy surely the problem you stated would exist in your code as it is **NOT AT ALL A PROBLEM** as far as python interpreter is considered.

See what you are doing

```
theatre[int(raw_input("Enter row"))][int(raw_input("Enter col"))]=="x" ## this doesn't work
```

is to compare if the value at a given point in the matrix is equal to `x` or not, so as far as your code goes python is comparing the given point and then just moving on to the next statement.

I would suggest that instead of asking here, it would be more helpful for you if you try to debug your code using `print()` statement or any debugger.